# Can't restart firewall by using Chef

Tags: ubuntu, chef-infra, firewall, ufw

I'm writing a cookbook for firewall to Ubuntu14.04 by using `Chef`.

### Berksfile

```
source "https://api.berkshelf.com"

cookbook 'firewall'
```

### site-cookbooks/ufw/recipes/default.rb

```
firewall 'ufw'

firewall_rule 'http' do
  port 80
end

firewall_rule 'https' do
  port 443
end
```

### site-cookbooks/ufw/metadata.rb

```
depends 'firewall'
```

### nodes/myserver.json

```
{
    "run_list": [
        "firewall",
        "ufw"
    ]
}
```

`knife solo cook myserver` ends up with error like this:

```
Recipe: firewall::default
  * firewall[default] action restart

    ================================================================================
    Error executing action `restart` on resource 'firewall[default]'
    ================================================================================

    NoMethodError
    -------------
    undefined method `include?' for :create:Symbol

    Cookbook Trace:
    ---------------
    /home/ironsand/chef-solo/cookbooks-3/firewall/libraries/provider_firewall_ufw.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in <class:FirewallUfw>'
    /home/ironsand/chef-solo/cookbooks-3/firewall/libraries/provider_firewall_ufw.rb:66:in `each'
    /home/ironsand/chef-solo/cookbooks-3/firewall/libraries/provider_firewall_ufw.rb:66:in `block in <class:FirewallUfw>'

    Resource Declaration:
    ---------------------
    # In /home/ironsand/chef-solo/cookbooks-3/firewall/recipes/default.rb

     22: firewall 'default' do
     23:   ipv6_enabled node['firewall']['ipv6_enabled']
     24:   action :install
     25: end
     26:

    Compiled Resource:
    ------------------
    # Declared in /home/ironsand/chef-solo/cookbooks-3/firewall/recipes/default.rb:22:in `from_file'

    firewall("default") do
      action [:install]
      updated true
      retries 0
      retry_delay 2
      default_guard_interpreter :default
      declared_type :firewall
      cookbook_name :firewall
      recipe_name "default"
      ipv6_enabled true
      enabled true
      rules {"ufw"=>{}}
    end
```

What I am doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: What version of Chef? You can see it displayed at the top of the `chef-client` output.

Comment: Also you shouldn't be using `api.berkshelf.com` anymore. It has nothing to do with this issue, but use `supermarket.chef.io` for your berks source.

Comment: @coderanger I was using `12.3.0` and updated to `12.8.1`, but the error remains same.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in the `firewall` cookbook. https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/firewall/blob/master/libraries/provider_firewall_ufw.rb#L67 should be casting the action to an array to be safe. If you set `action [:create]` on your firewall_rule` resource it will probably work.

Comment: I set `action [:create]`, but error remains same. I gonna use `execute method for `ufw`, it's not a good way though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should install the cookbook from Chef supermarket. See how to install here https://blog.chef.io/using-chef-supermarket-a-guided-tour. You need to guarantee coherence at `metadata.rb` and `Policyfile.rb`. Remove `Policyfile.lock.json` if are not getting any updates.  Add also `include_recipe 'firewall::default'`  to your recipe.